# Feign client method and java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Body parameter 1 was null

Tags: spring-boot, spring-restcontroller, feign

I have the following Feign client method:

```
@GetMapping
    RestPageImpl<CompanyDto> findAllCompanies(@RequestParam(value = "name", required = false) String name, Pageable pageable, @RequestHeader("Authorization") String token);
```

everything works fine when I pass not nullable `pageable` object, somehting like:

```
companyApiClient.findAllCompanies(null, PageRequest.of(0, 10, Sort.by(Sort.Direction.DESC, "c.createdAt")), null);
```

but in case of:

```
companyApiClient.findAllCompanies(null, null, null);
```

it fails with the following exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Body parameter 1 was null

    at feign.Util.checkArgument(Util.java:103)
```

How to allow nullable optional `pageable` object there?